# How to integrate the Etsy messenger in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, etsy

How can I integrate the Esty messenger with the WordPress website. I did not find any appropriate solution for this I also do google and check the Etsy forums but nothing found. Is there any way to integrate the messenger like the other messenger or chat tool that we use in website.

Currently I am using only the link of my Etsy profile that is something like [https://www.etsy.com/shop/{username}](https://www.etsy.com/shop/%7Busername%7D) but it just open the profile page instead of messenger.

This will show page something like below screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, Etsy do not have plans to support the messenger through their API at all. This is intentionally disallowed to avoid spam/abuse, so there is no official way to do this.